# Improper integral of an odd function

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals, even-and-odd-functions

would $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\ dx=0$ always be true if $f$ is an odd function?

Comment: If $\int_0^{\infty}f(x)\ dx$ exists then yes.

Comment: Yes.  Why do you doubt this?  What is your conceptual problem?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork If say $f(x) = x$ then one has to be careful about what is meant by $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\ dx$. It [doesn't exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral#Convergence_of_the_integral) as an improper integral, although its [principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) does exist and equals zero. Similar problem occurs with $f(x) = \sin(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true provided the integral is interpreted as [Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value#Formulation). Since $f$ is odd,
$$\int_{-A}^Af(x)\,dx=0 $$
Hence,
$$\mathrm{p.v. }\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx=\lim_{A\to\infty}\int_{-A}^Af(x)\,dx=0 $$
There's also the implicit assumption that $f$ is integrable in each interval $[-a,a]$. If we are not using principal values, then the improper integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx$ might not exist. For example, when $f(x)=x$, as @Bungo commented.